# jQuery load event for textarea on custom function

Tags: jquery, load, textarea

Trying to have a custom function where the text is in the input on page load so that its grouped with the rest of the function where the text creates "information" like text in the input. I have tried, `.load()`, `.bind('load')`, `.ready()` and I dont get anything. Just seeing if there might be a solution to this bump in the road.

```
//removed some of the validation code for simplicity. 

/*
to set a grey text infomation into a input field
*/
$.fn.greyInfo = function (text)
{

    //troubled code - start
    $(this).load(function()
    {
        $(this).val(text);
        $(this).css('color', 'grey');
    });
    //troubled code - end

    $(this).blur(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(this).val(text);
            $(this).css('color', 'grey');
        }
    });

    $(this).focus(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == text)
        {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        } 
    });

}
```

Comment: Found My Answer
`$(this).blur();`
put this at the end of the custom function

Comment: I don't think that load event triggered for $(this) in that context as I think it already triggered before your call , try to trigger it manual after you used that function for some object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the answer is simple, you don't need to call the function load as it is already there.

```
$.fn.greyInfo = function(text)
{

// you also don't need to reference $(this) as the jquery object is implied
        this.val(text);
        this.css('color', 'grey');


    $(this).blur(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == "")
        {
            $(this).val(text);
            $(this).css('color', 'grey');
        }
    });

    $(this).focus(function()
    {
        if($(this).val() == text)
        {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).css('color', 'black');
        } 
    });

};
```